# can't get functionpointer of template function - templateception

Tags: c++, function, templates

I want to pass a template function with template parameters into a function pointer but I do not get it working:

```
template <class T>
class tupel
{
public:
    tupel<T>(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {};
    T x;
    T y;
};

typedef tupel<int>(*fp)(tupel<int>);

template <tupel<int> &min, tupel<int> &max>
tupel<int> resize(tupel<int> size)
{
    tupel<int> result_size;

    result_size.x = (size.x >= max.x)?max.x:(size.x<=min.x)?min.x:size.x;
    result_size.y = (size.y >= max.y)?max.y:(size.y<=min.y)?min.y:size.y;

    return result_size;
}

void print_tupel(tupel<int> t)
{
    std::cout << t.x << "," << t.y << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    tupel<int> & tp = *(new tupel<int>(600,80));

    tupel<int>(*foo) &max>(tupel<int>) = resize<tp, tp>;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get a function pointer of this template function?

Comment: Also, std::function is really good at wrapping up things of horribly complex type, like lambdas.

Comment: `template <tupel<int> &min, tupel<int> &max>` declares two non-type template arguments (of reference type). The arguments you supply to those parameters have to be (names of) static objects, because template arguments need to be compile-time constants. There are some other possibilities with constant expressions, but certainly `tp` is not a valid argument, as it's referring to a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: `tupel<int> & tp = *(new tupel<int>(600,80));` <- this is generally a *very* bad idea. Objects created with `new` have to be deleted with `delete`, and typically you assume you don't need to destroy objects referred to *by a reference*.

Comment: `tupel<T>(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {};` Is rather uncommon; just use the *injected-class-name* `tuple(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}` and leave out the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your program will work:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class tupel
{
public:
    tupel<T>()
        : x(0), y(0)
    { }
    tupel<T>(T x, T y)
        : x(x), y(y)
    { }

    T x;
    T y;
};

typedef tupel<int> (*fp) (tupel<int>, tupel<int>, tupel<int>);

template<class T>
tupel<int> resize(T size, T max, T min)
{
    tupel<int> result_size;

    result_size.x = (size.x >= max.x) ? max.x : (size.x <= min.x) ? min.x : size.x;
    result_size.y = (size.y >= max.y) ? max.y : (size.y <= min.y) ? min.y : size.y;

    return result_size;
}

void print_tupel(tupel<int> t)
{
    std::cout << t.x << "," << t.y << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    tupel<int>& tp1 = *(new tupel<int>(600, 80));
    tupel<int>& tp2 = *(new tupel<int>(100, 800));
    tupel<int>& tp3 = *(new tupel<int>(200, 200));

    // assigning function pointer for template function.
    fp foo;
    foo = &resize<tupel<int>>;
    tupel<int> result = (*foo)(tp1, tp2, tp3);

    print_tupel(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tupel<int>& tp1 = *(new tupel<int>(600, 80));` In your example, I'd just use `tupel<int> tp1(600, 80);`. Not sure what the OP intended with this rather strange way to create a "named" object. `foo = &resize<tupel<int>>;` Here, `foo = &resize;` is even sufficient; the appropriate overload can be selected based on the type of `foo`.

Comment: You probably also want to use std::bind to bind tp2 & tp3 so that you have a function pointer you can just pass tp1 into.

Answer (score 0):

When I just tried calling resize at all, the compiler would have nothing of it:

```
tupel<int> tp(600,80); 
tupel<int> tumin(100, 200), tumax( 200, 800) ;

tupel<int> result= resize<tumin, tumax>( tp) ;

t.cpp:35:21: error: no matching function for call to 'resize'
        tupel<int> result= resize<tumin, tumax>( tp) ;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:15:13: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'min'
tupel<int> resize(tupel<int> asample)
```

I would suggest instead, creating a functor with storage:

```
template <class T>
  class resizor
  { 
    public:
      resizor(T amin, T amax) : min_(amin), max_(amax) { }
      T operator()(T & asample)
      {
        T result= asample ;

        result.x = (asample.x >= max_.x)?max_.x:(asample.x<=min_.x)?min_.x:asample.x;
        result.y = (asample.y >= max_.y)?max_.y:(asample.y<=min_.y)?min_.y:asample.y;
        return result ;
      }

    private:
      T min_, max_ ;
  } ;
```

And a helper function to make it cleaner to create:

```
template <class T>
  resizor<T> make_resizor(T amin, T amax) { return resizor<T>( amin, amax) ; }
```

Then you can just do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  tupel<int> tp(600,80);
  auto myresize= make_resizor( tupel<int>(100, 200), tupel<int>(400, 800) ) ; 

  tupel<int> result= myresize( tp) ; 
  print_tupel( result) ; 

  return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

> 400,200